# Error Using Simplescalar simulator :attempting to execute bogus opcode

Tags: c, gcc, simulator

I have recently started using simplescalar and am trying to run a code on `sim-safe.c`. Code aborts dump after this function:

```
int checkcounter1(int addr, unsigned char ciphertext[], unsigned long int key_schedule[], int address_size, int counter_size)  
    { 
    int pos; 
    int exp; 
    char ch[16]; 
    unsigned long int chunk;
    int counter; 
    aes_decrypt(ciphertext, ch, key_schedule, 128); 
    chunk=strtoul(ch,NULL,16);
    printf("\nInside checkcounter 1 and chunk is %lu\n",chunk); 
    counter=chunk/(address_size*counter_size);
    printf("\n counter is %d and addr is %d\n",counter,addr);
    if (addr==1)     
        return onchip;     
    else 
        {
        if (addr%2==0) 
        {
        counter=counter/counter_size;
        printf("\n in if1\n");

        } 
            else 
        {
        counter=counter%counter_size;
        printf("\nin if2,counter is %d\n",counter);

        }     

    return 0; 

}
```

Strange part is the statement "in If2, counter is 0" is printed and all the calculations before that point are correct. Not able to understand which opcode it is referring to.

Thanks for the help.